# Boilerplate text to invite domain experts not familiar with Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Suppose I send an e-mail to invite an expert in an Earth Science domain, unfamiliar with Stack Exchange, to come to the site.  How can I best formulate the e-mail?

Let's have CW answers in different categories:

- E-mail sent to an individual
- E-mail sent to a group (mailing list)

Comment: Don't use a boilerplate, that's spam.

Comment: @blunders disagree. Templates are useful (obviously they can be personalised), and are frequently sent round academic mailing lists as it is (e.g. conference announcements).

Comment: I suggest that for a for-individuals template it'd be useful to have it modular, i.e. at the least variations for sending it to an undergrad geological society committee member versus a postgrad versus a member of faculty... for members of faculty I'd suggest including the para from my template for mailing lists about particularly highlighting the new resource to grads/undergrads.

Comment: The template for personalized emails is personalized emails. Key is to create a reason per person you contact for them to want to read your email (enjoyed your paper, hearing you speak, etc) - and suggest how that very topic is of interest on ES.SE. You don't have to take my word for it, but I send 1000000s of emails a year, and in this case, when starting out, it calls for more target engagement. Doesn't mean you can't have a system, but best thing to do is send your first email today.

Comment: @gerrit: Any luck?

Answer (score 4):

As an example, here's what I just sent to the "Coastal list" mailing list:

> Dear Coastal List,
>
> Many of you will probably be aware of the stackoverflow.com website,
>   if you use it for help with coding problems. Many may also be aware
>   that this is part of a wider network, called Stack Exchange, which runs
>   Q&A sites on a range of topics.
>
> A new “Earth Sciences” site has recently entered a beta phase. This
>   phase is where Stack Exchange tries out a site for a period of between
>   a few months and a few years, to see whether it will gain the critical
>   mass of expert users to be viable. The scope of “Earth Sciences” has
>   been explicitly stated to include oceanography and related subjects,
>   so it might be of interest to people here.
>
> Like other Stack Exchange sites, it is community-moderated; good questions
>   and answers are rapidly upvoted, and unclear or otherwise poor ones
>   downvoted. The quality of questions is a bit variable at present in my
>   view – you will see quite a lot of popular science level questions –
>   but the quality of answers to them is often high, and there are a
>   number of academics involved in the site. It’s still early enough that
>   the people who get involved soon have a real chance to set the future
>   expectations for content on the site.
>
> The site is at http://earthscience.stackexchange.com, or you can view
>   just questions that have been tagged with “ocean” at
>   https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean?sort=active
>
> Come and have a look, and perhaps pass the link on to any students or
>   colleagues who might find it useful!
>
> Kind regards, Simon.

Hope that's helpful as an example. Obviously it's written to be specific to its target.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested template for academic mailing lists, but by all means rip it to shreds...:

> Dear all [or whatever local greeting is standard],
>
> I'd like to draw your attention to the new Earth Sciences Stack Exchange site. Stack Exchange is a community-run information-exchange and teaching network; the Earth Sciences site launched in mid-April and is currently in open beta. It is hoped that it will prove a vibrant new community supporting experts and students in all subdisciplines.
>
> Please particularly consider highlighting this new resource to grad and undergrad students: Stack Exchange provides excellent practice in teaching and in clear scientific communication, with feedback from the community on quality of answers - from written English to referencing and figure captioning - in a social setting.
>
> --signoff

Comment: Yep, that's spam.

Comment: I have yet to be convinced that it differs significantly from conference/postdoc/etc advertising.

Comment: Right, it doesn't, and that's spam.

Comment: We clearly move in very different circles. Sure people don't want them as the main traffic on a mailing list, but all of the academic mailing lists I'm on consider them not only fair game but _actively useful_.

Comment: Right, I contact people as "blunders" and get them to do things, I don't spam people... :-) ...Just try finding a single person that you believe did something interesting, email them saying you how it interesting, and link to a question that you're 80% sure they would be able to answer, but 5% of the users here could not. Just a single email, that's real "user" engagement, and you'll get more "high-value" users that way + plus you'll learn what "new" users think too. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Just as a reminder, we don't need massive numbers, just real numbers, spamming people won't get us to real numbers faster, nor will it lead to real growth; all my opinion, but I'm speaking from experience; meaning growing "stuff" that creates real value.

Comment: Are you aware that you're being staggeringly condescending and dismissive?

Comment: This fails to address some key points I would want to see. There exist forums and Q&A's at Yahoo, Usenet, Quora, Researchgate, and I'm sure many domain-specific locations.  I've personally found participation in Stack Exchange much more rewarding than in others, but a recipient not familiar with Stack Exchange might ignore the e-mail as "why yet another forum?".  I think a boilerplate text needs to address somehow why participation in ES SE might be more interesting/rewarding than elsewhere.

Comment: This is the first time I've participated in SE; very happy to make a structure happen around why it's more rewarding, but will need some key points to bounce off. :-)

Comment: @kaberett Sure, it's a good start!  I don't mean to sound negative.  Maybe others can go in and edit the post to add some more points.

Comment: @gerrit didn't think you were being! Just wanted to clarify what I'd need to make more words happen, but as I say I'm completely happy for other folk to edit :-)

Comment: @kaberett: That's not my intent, I'll reflect on the fact that I am sure it was not easy give me that feedback, and thank you for doing so too. Sorry!

Comment: @gerrit meta answers aren't editable by most of us :-P But I have "publicise ES.SE on my to-do list for today or tomorrow, so I shall reflect back on that to here as another answer

Comment: @Simon W: it is editable now!